# Association error within Rails 4 app with mongoid + simple_form + devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, simple-form, mongoid5

As mentioned on title, I made a Rails 4 app that contains

- mongoid (5.1.3)
- devise (4.2.0)
- simple_form (3.2.1)

I set up my app with commands below:

```
rails g mongoid:config
rails g simple_form:install --bootstrap
rails g devise:install
rails g devise User
rails g scaffold post title content:text user:references
```

I add the code below in `user.rb` model file to make association between two models:

```
  embeds_many :posts
```

When I run app and create a user on it, then I visit http://localhost:3000/posts/new to create a new post, I got the error below:

```
Started GET "/posts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-29 19:54:21 +0300
Processing by PostsController#new as HTML
MONGODB | Adding localhost:27017 to the cluster.
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | mongoblog_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | mongoblog_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.0009257450000000001s
  Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (134.4ms)
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (140.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 144ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_ids' for #<Post _id: 579b8a3d419a8f180afbb798, title: nil, content: nil>
Did you mean?  user?):
    4:   <div class="form-inputs">
    5:     <%= f.input :title %>
    6:     <%= f.input :content %>
    7:     <%= f.association :user %>
    8:   </div>
    9: 
   10:   <div class="form-actions">
  app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_posts__form_html_erb__2731111319355307354_47423040086160'
  app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_posts__form_html_erb__2731111319355307354_47423040086160'
  app/views/posts/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_posts_new_html_erb__3061427264044886497_70253725122920'
```

I searched it on search engine and here but there was nothing related with this issue. How can I fix it?

**TEMPORARY SOLUTION**:

Replacing `embeds_many` and `embedded_in` associations in model files with `has_many` and `belongs_to` makes the app work. By this replacement, it is possible to access `Post`s belongs to `User` or `User`s `Post`. I wonder whether it's possible to make association in first situation, using `embeds_many` and `embedded_in`.

Comment: this line causing the issue `<%= f.association :user %>` .. Rails is thinking or expecting the `user_id` column to be present in the `Post` model. because that is how Rails association works. But I never used Mongo, so not sure how this works in mongoid.

Comment: Hi @ArupRakshit! I've created `user` and `post` instances manually and associated with each other properly. When I use `embeds_many` & `embedded_in` in models respectively, then I call `Post.first.user` on Rails console, I got `NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass` error. But when I replace them with `has_many` & `belongs_to`, suprisingly got this one: `#<User _id: BSON::ObjectId('579b85a9419a8f15c65fb65d'), email: "blablabla@gmail.com">`